# Safari and Chrome displaying jQuery mobile fieldcontain

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

In my HTML5 webapp I have a fieldcontain with a placeholder, say "Volume". Chrome displays the placeholder like it should do, but Safari doesn't display it at all. What could be the problem? Did I do smth. wrong?
Here is the code snippet:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="Liter">Liter:</label>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="36000" name="Liter" id="Liter" value="" placeholder="Liter" data-clear-btn="true"/>
</div>
```

Safari for Windows v. 5.1.7; Chrome for Windows v. 31.0.1650.63 m; jQuery v. 1.9.1; jQuery mobile v. 1.3.2

Comment: I edited the question: so why Safari doesn't display the 'placeholder="Liter"'?

Answer (score 0):

`placeholder` is not yet supported for every browser.

I always use ***jQuery*** for placeholders. An example using HTML5 Placeholder Fix JS:

```
$("'[placeholder]'").focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == input.attr("'placeholder'")) {
    input.val("''");
    input.removeClass("'placeholder'");
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == "''" || input.val() == input.attr("'placeholder'")) {
    input.addClass("'placeholder'");
    input.val(input.attr("'placeholder'"));
  }
}).blur();
```

Take a read here:
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: Well, according to that table there should be support of placeholder by Safari 5+ and I have Safari v. 5.7.1 so i still do not understand it